# function equation with translation of independent variable: $\frac{f(x+a)}{f(a)}=g(x)$

Tags: functional-equations

The following has come up in some work I'm doing: If $\frac{f(x+a)}{f(a)}=g(x)$, where $g(x)$  is given and $a \ge 0$ is a constant, what is $f(x)$? We can assume that $g(x)>0 \ \forall x$ . Of course a solution would be great, but I'd appreciate even general information on this equation, such as how it would be referred to (functional equation with translation?), similar equations, etc. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x+a)/f(x)$?

Comment: No, the denominator really is $f(a)$

Comment: Then it's trivial; $f(x+a)=g(x)f(a)$, so $f(x)=g(x-a)f(a)$, where $f(a)$ is arbitrary and $g(0)$ must be equal to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = e^x$, in fact:
$$f(x+a) = e^{x+a} = e^x e^{a} = f(a) g(x)$$

Note that $g(x) = e^x > 0 ~ \forall x$ as for hypotesis.

Comment: $g(x)$ is given, you can't pick it. For example, $g(x)$ may be specified as $x^2$, $1/(1+|x|)$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We have $f(x)=f(x-a+a)=g(x-a)f(a)$. Especially for $x=a$ we have $f(a)=g(0)f(a)$ and as $f(a)\neq 0$ we must have $g(0)=1$. This means there exists a solution only if $g(0)=1$ and in that case it is $f(x)=g(x-a)c$ where the constant $f(a)=c$ can be chosen.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I came up with too but I got stuck on the step   $f(x)=g(x-a)f(a)$ and didn't see that $f(a)$ could be arbitrary.

Comment: @GregReese BTW, you can vote or tick this answer, to close the topic.